# tcl read variables with the same prefix

Tags: tcl

I have a variables with the same prefix. For example:

```
set prefix1Postfix 89
set prefix2Postfix 56 
set prefix3Postfix 56
```

So is it possible iterate over them by this way:

```
set l [list prefix1 prefix2 prefix3]

foreach item $l {
     puts "item = ${{$l}Postfix}"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Tcl is interpreting the `{$l` part as a variable following the first opening and closing brace it encounters:

```
puts "item = ${{$l}Postfix}"
              ^---^
```

And the variable should have been `$item` as well ;) The braces also prevent substitution, so that Tcl will look for literal `$item` if you use braces.

One workaround you can use is to assign a variable to the suffix:

```
set prefix1Postfix 89
set prefix2Postfix 56 
set prefix3Postfix 56

set l [list prefix1 prefix2 prefix3]
set p "Postfix"

foreach item $l {
     puts "item = [set $item$p]"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this scenario, the general advice is that it's easier to use arrays

```
set prefixPostfix(1) 89
set prefixPostfix(2) 56 
set prefixPostfix(3) 56

foreach key [array names prefixPostfix] {
    do something with $prefixPostfix($key)
}
```